# Selecting with non-class tag in scrapy python

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrap title of a website but the problem it has no class and id.

Usually i use this to get title that has class:

```
titles = response.xpath('//a[@class="result-title hdrlnk"]/text()').extract()
```

Now I am trying to extract text, please see the screenshot, can you please fix it? [https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6aCN.png][1]

Answer (score 1):

You may locate a specific node by any attribute (not only class and id) or its relative position with some others.

A few examples for the text in your screenshot:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="job-title-text"]/a/text()')
response.xpath('//a[contains(@onclick,"clickJObTitle")]/text()')
response.xpath('//a[contains(@href,"jobdetails")]/text()')
response.css('div.job-title-text a::text')
response.css('a[onclick*=clickJObTitle]::text')
response.css('a[href*=jobdetails]::text')
```

See also:

- https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp